# Undo function using self made "deepcopy"?

Tags: python, list, deep-copy, undo

I want to create an `undo()` function that undoes the last operation in python, so I just deepcopied the list before any modifications were made during whatever function to another list (I made a bootleg `deepcopy` by myself), called `undolist`, and then when I call `undo()` I just pop the last element from the `undolist`

I know there are other more efficient ways of doing this, but given my time constraints and my mental in-capabilities I don't think I could turn this in.

However, it doesn't work. I am going to post an example of how I implemented the undo function and the bootleg `deepcopy` on a random function, since the code itself is super long and in another language

I hope I've made myself clear enough, if there are any misunderstandings I'll edit the post.

```
main_list = [list of lists that have elements in them]


def bootleg_deepcopy(main_list):
    new_list = []
    for x in main_list:
        nx = x[:]
        new_list.append(nx)
    return new_list
    
    
def delete_elements(main_list,user_input,undolist):
    #function that deletes elements from the list if a condition isn't met
    undolist.append(bootleg_deepcopy(main_list))
    main_list[:] = [element for element in main_list if not function_that_checks_something(whatever,something)]
    return main_list


def undo(main_list,undolist):
    try:
        main_list = undolist.pop()
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)
    return main_list
```

Comment: How are you calling `undo()`? You need to assign `main_list = undo(main_list, undolist)`.

Comment: @Barmar inside the function where I call all of the functions I call undo by ```undo(main_list, undolist)```. Are you saying that I should make another function, say ```ui_undo(main_list,undolist)``` where I print the main_list? I'm sorry, I didn't really understand what you mean

Comment: @Barmar ok so what I did now was I created a ```ui_undo(main_lis, undolist)``` function that basically just prints a message like "undid operation" and does what you said to assign and it prints the unmodified list, however it doesn't update the original list 
it's kind of like a shallow undo if you will

Comment: You either need to change `undo` to do a slice assignment, or you need to assign the result to the global `main_list` variable.

Comment: @Barmar so something like ```main_list[:] = undolist.pop()``` ?

Comment: Yeah, just like you do in `delete_elements`

Comment: it worked! thanks a lot!

Comment: Preferably you shouldn't render the question meaningless by removing the problem in the code; better is to post the solution as an _Answer_.

Comment: true @Armali, I'll edit it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to use the slice operator(?) in the `undo()` function. I've edited it so that it includes the right code.

```
def undo(main_list,undolist):
    try:
        main_list[:] = undolist.pop()
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)
    return main_list
```

Answer (score 2):

Your undo simply returns a new reference to main_list. Your delete_elements method overwrites the main_list in-place (`main_list[:] = ...`). I assume you want the same behavior in your undo action so that all places that hold references to main_list are updated automatically.

Comment: right, yes, I tried doing what barmar told me but I think I may have implemented it in a wrong way since it just prints a new list instead of updating the old one (check the comments in the OP)